# Set rows' values for the next 5 rows when value of the row is X (SQL table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

- The table has three columns. (1) UserID, (2) Date, (3) Status.
- There are X users, each has the same date ranges log of their statuses.
- Statuses (currently) are either "Active" or null.
- It could be that there are 5 "Active" days in the row, or it could be 20 days between them.

**The goal I'm trying to achieve is:** on the date when user's status is "Active", set statuses of the next 5 dates as "Phantom" (or whatever else).

Before:

```
UserID   Date      Status
000001   01-01-17  null
000001   02-01-17  Active
000001   03-01-17  null
000001   04-01-17  null
000001   05-01-17  null
000001   06-01-17  null
000001   07-01-17  null
000001   08-01-17  null
000001   09-01-17  Active
000001   10-01-17  null
```

After:

```
UserID   Date      Status
000001   01-01-17  null
000001   02-01-17  Active
000001   03-01-17  Phantom
000001   04-01-17  Phantom
000001   05-01-17  Phantom
000001   06-01-17  Phantom
000001   07-01-17  null
000001   08-01-17  null
000001   09-01-17  Active
000001   10-01-17  Phantom
```

I've tried to approach the problem from two angles:
a) As a cycle, that would check whether within the previous X rows 'Active' value is present 
b) To select rows that where status is 'Active' and the X rows after them into temp table and to join them afterwards

I assume it should be a way to check "whether the value X is present between Date and Date+X" yet I failed to achieve this so far.

Would very much appreciate help on how to achieve that! (MSSQL)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Apologies for making it look that way and thank you for your comment! Very much appreciate your time and advice. Never used this service to ask own questions before. I updated the topic slightly yet without adding my code as I believe it is a trash and would be confusing. (I described approaches I tried and considered as a potential solution instead.) May do so, of course, if necessary.

Comment: If not your code, please include the **before** and **after** of the data.

Comment: @FDavidov, done. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @diiN__________, I've updated my post slightly. Thank you for the fair comment! Lacking experience of asking own questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to find a solution. Two steps. First, I create a temp table (#active_dates) where I put only rows with 'Active' status. Then, I run the following script:

```
update   table_name
set      status='Phantom' 
from     #active_dates as a 
where    a.userid=table_name.userid and 
         (table_name.[date] between a.[date] and dateadd(day,5,a.[date])) and
         (table_name.status is null)
```

Where 5 is just a number of rows after 'Active' one want's to update.

Thank you for your time if you read this. :)

Comment: Fair solution. Please note that in your **AFTER** example you have an error... The last record (`10-01-17`) should be `Phantom` and not `null`.